# SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file on FTP server

Tags: php, sqlite, ftp

I'm able to open local db files. But, I cannot open files that are on server using ftp.

Here is how I am listing files. Accessing to files are successful, cos if I echo `$ftpcontents[$i]` it can list the file names

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($ftpcontents); $i++){
 if (strripos($ftpcontents[$i],".db")==true) {
    $thefiles[$countdirfiles] = $ftpcontents[$i];
    $countdirfiles++;
 }

}
```

Connecting to sqlite

```
try {

    $file_db = new PDO('sqlite:'.$thefiles[$i]);
    $file_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = $selectquery." main.".$tablename." ".$groupquery." ";;

    $result = $file_db->query($sql);
    $file_db = null;

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This is the error message I'm getting

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

Answer (score 0):

Create a property:

```
private $file_db;
try{
    if($file_db==null){
      $file_db; =new PDO('sqlite:'.$thefiles[$i]);
    }
    return $this->$file_db;
}catch(PDOException $e){
    logerror($e->getMessage(), "opendatabase");
    print "Error in openhrsedb ".$e->getMessage();
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The File Transfer Protocol (FTP) is a standard network protocol used to transfer computer files between a client and server on a computer network. FTP is built on a client-server model architecture and uses separate control and data connections between the client and the server.

FTP can be used for only to upload or download files.

We **cannot open files directly from FTP**